# How to enable Content Grouping in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to find where "Content Grouping" settings are located in Google Analytics.

In their [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167) they say:

1. Click Admin at the top of any Analytics page.
2. Use the menu in the View column to select the view you want.
3. Click Content Grouping.

I can't find "Content Grouping" in my menu:

[image]

I checked "Custom Channel Groupings" but it doesn't look similar to what is being described in the docs.

I am using *ga.js* tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New features are rolled out incrementally, not all at once to all accounts (I'm looking at some 30 client accounts and they pretty much all show a slightly different feature set at the moment. Only one as content groupings (different country than the others, so this might be rolled out on a per-country basis)).

So you can't activate content groupings, they will appear at some point in the future when Google updates your account.